# Using opencv's ptr pointer to manipulate pixels

Tags: opencv

I used opencv to read in a picture and split the image. 
The divided matrix:

1. Odd rows are odd columns as A matrix;
2. The odd-numbered rows are evenly listed as B-matrices;
3. The odd-numbered rows are evenly listed as C-matrices;
4. Even-numbered even-numbered columns are D-matrices;

**My code:**

```
void SplitMat(Mat& src, Mat& objA, Mat& objB, Mat& objC, Mat& objD) {
// src:  Input image,  CV_16UC1
// objA: Output image, CV_16UC1
// objB: Output image, CV_16UC1
// objC: Output image, CV_16UC1
// objD: Output image, CV_16UC1

Mat dst;
src.copyTo(dst);
int row, col, i, j;
for (row = 0, i = 0; row < dst.rows - 1; row = row + 2, ++i) {
    ushort* temp0 = dst.ptr<ushort>(row);
    ushort* temp1 = dst.ptr<ushort>(row + 1);
    ushort* obja = objA.ptr<ushort>(i);
    ushort* objb = objB.ptr<ushort>(i);
    ushort* objc = objC.ptr<ushort>(i);
    ushort* objd = objD.ptr<ushort>(i);
    for (col = 0, j = 0; col < dst.cols - 1; col = col + 2, ++j) {
        obja[j] = temp0[col];
        objb[j] = temp0[col + 1];
        objc[j] = temp1[col];
        objd[j] = temp1[col + 1];
    }
}
```

}

**Test result**:
[image]

**I don't know why the image in the x direction has become two images.**

> Please guide us. Is this a logical error or something else? thanks

Comment: maybe because you are iterating over 2 images in different steps? Can you ecplain what you are doing there and what you want to achive? Wuy dont you just use a single iteration variable?

Comment: I just want to try to test the theoretical model of polarization thermal imaging. This model needs to split the original (polarized) image for analysis.

Comment: If you can, use CV_8UC1 instead of CV_16UC1 to solve the problem

Comment: can you explain how you have to split from a per pixel/element point of view (small example of a row)?  You still have to tell how the input-output parameters were initialized. Can you share that part of the code, probably shortly before `SplitMat` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason for this problem. Since the picture read is 8 bits, and the program uses 16 bits.
`uchar -> ushort` have a question.